# Ĉu streĉi aŭ malstreĉi muskolojn post trejnado?

Tags: translation

Dum parolado oni celis la saman ideon sed uzis malajn vortojn.

Jen pli malpli la situacio:

```
A. Mia kapo doloregas, eble pro kontrakturo
B. Nu, vi povus dolĉe movi ĝin dekstren maldekstren
   supren malsupren por etendi la kolajn muskolojn
A. Bona ideo, por streĉi ilin
B. Fakte, estus por malstreĉi, ĉu?
```

Laŭ PIV, [streĉi](https://vortaro.net/#stre%C4%89i_kd) povas signifi (inter pluraj ebloj):

1. Forte tiri malrigidan objekton k teni ĝin en pli longigita aŭ pli larĝigita stato
2. En alta grado uzi sian korpan forton por ia movo, gesto

La rigidiĝon kaj mallongigon muskolan povas kaŭzi la ago priskribita en dua signifo, kaj en tiu momento ebla solvo estas etendo de tiuj muskoloj, kiu iel pensigas pri la unua signifo.

Do, ŝajne ambaŭ agoj estus streĉoj, kaj la rigidiga kaj la etenda ...

Pro simetriaj kialoj, mi dirus malstreĉi muskolojn post trejnado (ĉar mi ilin unue streĉis), sed ĉu tio ĝustas?

Comment: Por trovi "muskolo(j)n" en Tekstaro, oni [serĉu je `muskoloj?n`](https://tekstaro.com/?s=61c1251178800). La vorto aperas kaj kun "streĉi" kaj kun "malstreĉi", sed mi ne en ĉiu kunteksto tie certas pri la signifo.

Answer (score 1):

Oni uzas **"etendi"** ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#etendi), [ReVo](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-2a.html?q=etendi)) pli-malpli tia-sence ja pri korpaj membroj (brakoj & kruraj):

> Erst des Nachts […] erwachte das kleine Gespenst. Pünktlich beim zwölften Glockenschlag öffnete es die Augen und **reckte und streckte sich**.

— [Otfried Preußler](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otfried_Preussler): [Das Kleine Gespenst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_kleine_Gespenst)

> Nur [… je noktomezo …] la malgranda fantomo vekiĝadis. Sampempe kun la dek-dua horloĝa bato ĝi malfermis la okulojn kaj **etendis la membrojn**.

— Traduko [La malgranda fantomo](https://www.kava-pech.cz/#/eo/b/YUA8cBEAACMAXGE1/la-malgranda-fantomo) de [Kirilo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_Robert_Brosch) ([@cyril-robert-brosch](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/users/858/cyril-robert-brosch))

… do eble oni ĝin uzu tiel ankaŭ pri muskoloj (kiel "B." en via konversacio ja faris), ĉu?

Comment: Jes, etendi bonas. Mi ŝatus scii tamen ĉu vere ambaŭ malaj formoj povus esprimi la samon ... Estas iel ĝene.